# "Не дарить подарки" или "не дарить подарков"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, дополнение

Не дарить подарки или не дарить подарков?

Answer (score 2):

Если речь о конкретных подарках, то "Не дарить (эти) подарки", "Я решила не дарить подарки, которые я приготовила", а если о подарках вообще, то "Не дарить подарков (вообще)", "Я решила никогда не дарить подарков".

Подробнее можно прочитать у Розенталя [(§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04))